# Compiler error when using thrust placeholders with the ternary operator ?:

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am using Thrust 1.8 and I get two compiler errors when I try to compile the below code :

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    thrust::device_vector<bool> condition(100); 
    thrust::device_vector<int> input(100); 
    thrust::device_vector<float> result(100);
    float mean = 10.4f;

    thrust::transform(condition.begin(),condition.end(),input.begin(),result.begin(), ( (thrust::placeholders::_1 ) ? ( thrust::placeholders::_2) : (mean) ) );
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following compiler time errors :

(for placeholders::_1)

> Error : Expression must be of  bool type (or convertible to bool)

(for placeholders::_2)

> Error : operand types are incompatible ("const thrust::detail::functional::actor < thrust::detail::functional::argument<1U>>" and "float")

How to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the placeholders like you tried to, i.e. in combination with a ternary operator.

Instead, you could create your own functor:

```
struct my_fun : public thrust::binary_function<bool,float,float>
{
   float mean;
   my_fun(float mean) : mean(mean) {}
   __host__ __device__
   float operator()(bool condition, float input) const
   {
        float result = mean;
        if (condition)
        {
             result = input;
        }
        return result;
    }
};

...

thrust::transform(condition.begin(),
                  condition.end(),
                  input.begin(),
                  result.begin(),
                  my_fun(mean));
```

Comment: @RobertCrovella I only tested it with zeros and ones, which worked. You are right, it does not work for arbitrary values so I removed it. Thanks for pointing it out.